# dataTransfer.setData of drag&drop doesn't work in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

```
<div id="asd" title="222">drag me</div>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById("asd");
el.draggable=true;
el.addEventListener("dragstart", function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var dt = ev.dataTransfer;
    dt.effectAllowed = "copyMove";
        console.log(this.getAttribute("title") + " attr");
    dt.setData('Text', this.getAttribute("title"));
        console.log(dt.getData('Text') + " dt");
},false);
</script>
```

FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/vwjCa/

http://jsfiddle.net/vwjCa/2/ (custom type here instead of text)

in firefox prints:

```
222 attr
222 dt
```

in chrome prints:

```
222 attr
 dt
```

where is the problem here?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

answering to myself:

apparently chrome allows to read dataTransfer's data **only in the drop event**

this is for security reason

for instance if I "drag over" a credit card number on a remote page, this one should not be able to read my data unless i have not "dropped"

firefox does the same, but allows to read getData() if "domain" of events is the same

Answer (score 3):

There is a [bug in chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31037) that allows you only to use certain mime-types. Try to change `'Text'` in your code to `'text/plain'`, that should work in chrome.